# Installation from Live USB doesn't find my partitions

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, sony, secure-boot

I have a Sony Win8 ultrabook. When I boot from a live USB, Ubuntu 12.10 will access my partial SSD to access data.

But when I go to install it, it gets to the point of changing partitions, but shows none at all. It throws an error, but will not allow me to install Ubuntu.

It does this whether I have Secure Boot enabled or not, same with Legacy Boot.

I contacted Sony to see if they could help, but all I got was "Sorry, but Sony doesn't support Ubuntu. We love Win 8 and only support that" kind of response.

So here I am... Please help!

Preferably, I'd prefer a dual boot --- my wife likes Win 8. And I've had a few successful dual boots with Win8, but only on HP computers.

Comment: What's the error that you get?

Comment: You have obsolete package versions installed. Please upgrade the following packages and check if the problem still occurs: als-base, apt, apt-utils, aptdaemon, base-files, busybox-initrams, consolekit, coreutils, dmsetup, ecryptsfs-utils ----- and it keeps listing a bunch of other packages

Comment: Should I try installing 13.04 from a dvd? Would it make a difference?

Comment: Simply upgrade all upgradable packages by running `sudo apt-get upgrade` in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the hard drive out of the equation as the problem.  Do you have another hard drive to try an install with?  If it installs then we'll know it's an issue with the SSD.  Possibly an encrypted hard drive?

Comment: hmm... not tried that.. i do have another hd I can try. how and why would the ssd be encrypted? and if so, how would I unencrypt it?

Comment: I think we have an encrypted drive.. I put my old HDD in this computer, loaded the live USB, and installed Ubuntu over my old OS... Works great.. But it's an old hd that's kinda tiny, so I'd like to use my new one, which is 32 gb ssd and 500 hdd. Help!!!